# Show files in folder while using FolderPicker

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there any possible way to show the files in the folders when using `FolderPicker` ?

Code :

```cs
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

return await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the WindowsAPICodepack, you can do it like so:

```
var openFolder = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
openFolder.AllowNonFileSystemItems = true;
openFolder.Multiselect = true;
openFolder.IsFolderPicker = true;
openFolder.Title = "Select folders.";

if (openFolder.ShowDialog() != CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No folder selected.");
    return;
}

// get all the directories in selected directory
var dirs = openFolder.FileNames.ToArray();
```

However if you're using just `Windows.Storage.Pickers`, the code you've provided is the example given on the Microsoft docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker), so I'm not too sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, the docs say that your given example should show all files in folders, take a look.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, you can always try WinApiCodepack-Core and Shell on Nuget.

Comment: The WinApiCodepack-Core is not fully compatible with my project.

Answer (score 0):

For the built-in FolderPicker, it's impossible. You could call the 'StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync' method to get the files in the current folder.

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

foreach (var files in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(files.DisplayName);
}
```

If you want to show these files on the UI, you could choose some list controls to show them. For example, [List view and grid view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview).

Comment: No because I only want to show them while picking the folder because I want the user to know what's in the folder he's about to pick.

Comment: As I said, for the built-in FolderPicker, it's impossible. You could try to submit a **'Feature Request'** on [WPDev UserVoice](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/).